# how to set events width in fullcalendar 4.0 day mode

Tags: calendar, fullcalendar

I tried to set the events width properly in day mode irrespective of the number of events.
Not able to properly display it as in the attached image .

And another issue is I am using eventlimit:3 in initialization of the calendar, can we set the same attribute with different value for the week mode such as "20" at the time of initialization, though I can set it dynamically with setOption method, Please suggest.

[image]

Comment: "can we set the same attribute with different value for the week mode"...yes this is mentioned in the documentation  - see the last sentence of https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/eventLimit . It's done using [view-specific options](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/view-specific-options).

Comment: "Not able to properly display it"...what result were you expecting exactly? It's unclear what you feel the problem is in that picture. You've set a fixed width, and that appears to be the outcome you got.

Comment: Hi @ADyson, in the attached image the events are rendered based on the number of events, it seems good, it is not a full calendar, in my case in day mode at a particular time like at 11.00PM, only 3 events are there, they occupying the complete row width and more than normal height also. I want to display the events as similar as the last 2 events in the attached screen.

Comment: _"they occupying the complete row width"_ ...that's how fullCalendar normally displays events. If you've tried to alter that, you'd have to show precisely what code changes you made. Although I wouldn't recommend doing it really, it will mess with the algorithms fullCalendar uses to ensure events don't overlap, that sort of thing.  _"more than normal height"_ ...you mean they end after their proper finish time? That's likely to be a problem you've introduced by changing some CSS, or having CSS which conflicts with fullCalendar's. Again without a reproducible code example I can't say exactly.

Comment: ok, and another one is I am not using NEXT and PREV buttons of full calendar, for the similar functionality I written jquery code with the help of gotoDate function and own ajax calls, but some times(mostly for the first time) in case of view changed(month/view/day) in addition of my own ajax request in my own function , the default fullcalendar events ajax call also simultaneously triggered, can we disable the default call of full calendar once it initialized, it is not related to lazyFetching: true(I already used it to avoid unnecessary calls with in the month for multiple views). Thank you

Comment: that sounds like a completely separate issue, so please ask a new question about it, formatted properly and with a clear code examples. Come on, you should know how this works by now!

Comment: Hi @ADyson, posted the request, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62679797/fullcalendar-prev-and-next-buttons-functionality-overriding-by-own-jquery-functi