# Fullcalendar PREV and Next buttons functionality overriding by own jquery functions

Tags: calendar, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar 4.0, with setting header:false, then overriding next & prev buttons functionalities with own functions, facing issue when click on any one of my own button for the first time only after initialization of full calendar, please find the code:

```
 var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
 all default initializations here;
 header: false,
 events: {
 url: '../../classes/calendar/Calendar.XXX? method=getCellsforCalendar&startDate='+startDate+'&endDate='+endDate+'&startYear='+startYear+'&startMonth='+startMonth+'&returnformat=json',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: true,
}//It return an array structure so directly all events are rendered on calendar
}//calendar code ends here

//my own function for NEXT button.
$('#nextBtn').click(function() {
 calendar.gotoDate(date_here);

//If need new other events
$.when( $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: URL_HERE,
   success: function (response) {
   responseArray = JSON.parse(response);
   calendar.addEventSource(responseArray); //before this line I deleted existing event sources
}
});
```

Here when I click on Next button for the first time after initialization of full calendar, 2 ajax calls are triggered , one is next button ajax request(this is expected one) and the other is the ajax request URL mentioned in the events: section(with the selected default start and end parameters) of full calendar initialization, once I click on next, for remaining clicks on same button or any other custom buttons, only the expected ajax request will be triggering. Any idea please. And also it's not related to lazyloading:true, I already set it to avoid unnecessary ajax rewuests. Thanks .

Comment: You're not using the calendar as it's intended to be used. If you need to download extra events which are not supplied from your main URL, then you can specify multiple event sources in your setup. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/eventSources

Comment: Also. your main events URL does not make much sense...I mean this one: `url: '../../classes/calendar/Calendar.XXX? method=getCellsforCalendar&startDate='+startDate+'&endDate='+endDate+'&startYear='+startYear+'&startMonth='+startMonth+'&returnformat=json',` Where is `startDate`, `endDate` etc coming from? It looks like these will be fixed always after the calendar is initialised? But that isn't good, because you want to get different events depending on the time period the calendar is showing...

Comment: ... As per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/events-json-feed, fullCalendar will send "start" and "end" fields to your server automatically by appending them to your supplied URL before it makes the request. It will do this whenever it finds that you change the view to a date for which it doesn't already have events loaded  in the calendar. Putting your own date fields separately  in the URL isn't necessary and isn't logical.

Comment: Hi @ADyson, startdate and enddate are the currentmonthstart-7 and currentmontend+7 at the time of initialization, for further button clicks based on the calendar.activestart and activeend values I calculated the required dates which need to be supplied, If this is not the case, how can we put our required OR own code in fullcalendar defined PREV and NEXT buttons logic.

Comment: And I need the start and end dates(monthstart-7, monthend+7) which are not exactly same as full calendar passes automatically as month start and month end, before my approach I followed $('.fc-button-prev span').click(function(){
   alert('prev is clicked, do something');
});

$('.fc-button-next span').click(function(){
   alert('nextis clicked, do something');
});  as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788761/how-to-call-events-on-clicking-prev-and-next-button, which is not at all working.

Comment: " I need the start and end dates(monthstart-7, monthend+7)"...but why? That won't be shown on the calendar. You only need the month that is actually being shown.

Comment: If you _really_ want to change the dates sent for some reason, then use the [events-as-a-function](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function) pattern and construct your own AJAX request - therefore you can get the supplied start/end dates and add/subtract the days from them as you please, before sending to the server. But I can't understand why it would be necessary really.